# How to Sync my CMS users with Wordpress users?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, synchronization, content-management-system

We've designed a CMS which has a table called users. Some of our customers use Wordpress beside our CMS. They need to sync Wordpress users with our CMS users so that the user does not need to sign up two times...
What's the best and easiest solution?

Answer (score 0):

**For single sign in:**
It Depends on your CMS and what sort of Login technology it uses to keep the users logged in. If its not a scalable system then, mostly it would use sessions to keep the users logged in, while for scalable systems, mostly cookies are used.

On wordpress end you can use this hook. It will be triggered right after the user is logged into wordpress.

```
<?php
function your_function($user_login, $user) {
    // first lookup the user in wordpress 
    // Then use an api call to login the user in your cms
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
?>
```

Similarly you need to do this on your CMS as well, inside the login authentication function/method. You can use this api for wordpress to log the user in from your CMS.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/

**For single signup :**
Single signup is much more simpler than the login, for wordpress you can use user_register hook that is triggered right after the user is registered. You can then create a very simple api in your CMS which takes in the user details and adds them to the CMS or if both the systems are ssl certified then you can use a simple post request to send data to and fro the CMS.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'register_user_in_cms', 10, 1 );

function register_user_in_cms( $user_id ) {
  // accessing the data of user, and then send a post request to CMS
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't mean login process, I mean Signup process... I want to add the user to my users table when the user registers in wordpress... Is "MySQL Event" a good solution? How can I use it?

Comment: Thats even simpler then single signin, checkout my edit